# Report asking for credentials from shared DS with saved credentials

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have two report both using the same shared datasource which has the 'credentials stored securely in the report server' ticked and connection tested successfully.  However one report still asks for username/pw while the other report does not.  I can enter in the credentials and the report runs but obvisouly this is not the way it's intended to work.  I have also checked the report in Studio and there the datasource is also using stored credentials.  Report runs fine from within Studio.  I have taken the datasource guid from the working report xml and placed it in the other report which still runs fine in Studio but once deployed to reportserver still asks username/pw.  I'm really at a loss on what I could be  missing or option checked/unchecked.  Any one got sometihng else I could try?

Comment: Are you sure that the datasource is asking you for credentials?  Without seeing the prompt, it might be the report asking.  Are you viewing the report in IE?

Comment: It's the report asking.  The shared DS works fine for two other reports.  I am viewing in IE.

Comment: Is the security on the 2 reports the same?

Comment: I think your issue is indeed datasources are different on two reports  Goto working report in report server and goto to Properties -> datasource tab. Compare its data source with the non working report.

Comment: Can you double check that the report only has the one datasource?

Comment: Both reports are only pointing to the same shared datasource.

Comment: Is your non-working dataset referring to another database that doesn't have the same permissions?

Comment: Both refer to the same DB